# How to get only one element

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example I have a function that has one argument, it can be DOM element ID or className.
How can I select only first element wrapped with jQuery?

`$(value).get(0)` and `$(value)[0]` returns just the plain DOM element, not a jQuery wrapped element.

Comment: Can you make this question understandable?

Comment: @mbq Please give some constructive criticism. However, the question seems clear enough - How does one select the first element when using JQuery selectors?

Comment: @cofiem You must admit it was at least hard to read; but now it is ok thanks to jensgram and Ólafur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(value).eq(0);
// or
$(value).first();
// or
$(value + ':eq(0)');
// or
$(value + ':first');
```

Comment: The method forms like `first()` are always to be preferred over the selector versions like `:first`. These are non-standard selectors, which will force jQuery to use the relatively slow Sizzle library to do selector matching instead of the browser's fast native `querySelectorAll()`.

Answer (score 4):

```
$(value).first();
```

See http://api.jquery.com/first/

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the `.first()` method constructs a new jQuery object from the first matching element.

Comment: There are plenty of ways (cf. the other answers). You can even wrap the result from `$(value)[0]` or `$(value).get(0)` again, e.g., `$($(value)[0])` :)

Comment: +1, this is about ten times faster than using `:first`, according to some dude called 'moltendorf' who posted a benchmark in the comments section of the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/first/#comment-37524554

Comment: @karim79 - the faster version would be `.eq(0)` though, since it's an alias :) @jensgram - pleeeeeeease don't do that, it's tremendously wasteful and less flexible :)

Comment: @Nick Craver I assume you're referring to the horrible `$($(value)[0])`. The smiley was meant to emphasize that this was even *another* way ... a way to avoid, though. @Roman *Don't!*

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) (if it's a selector), like this:

```
$(value:first)
```

Or [`.eq(0)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) like this:

```
$(value).eq(0)
```

Or [`.first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) (just an alias for `.eq(0)`) like this:

```
$(value).first()
```